# Google Chrome HTML5 video caching

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching, video

I developing a website. Now a added a HTML5 video. This works fine.
The problem is if I change the video file in the background. So the user can upload a new video file. Chrome still gets the old video URL but playes the old video from cache. 
It even playes the cached video after restarting chrome.
When I disable the cache everything is fine.

Hope someone can help me.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The video server implementation sent a expires header which was set in the future. So chrome thought it is not required to reload resource.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing F12 and then right click on reload symbol/icon you can select

`'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'`